# ReactJs - (Internal Server Error) Error: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: reactjs

I have written code for submitting new form but the axios post request is not going through, the error I am getting is:

POST http://localhost:3000/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

SignUp.js:36 Error: Request failed with status code 500

at createError (createError.js:16:1)

at settle (settle.js:17:1)

at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)

I am using proxy in package.json file
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/api/"

```
import React from "react-dom";
import LeftSide from "./MainBody/LeftSide";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        try{            
            const res = await axios.post("/auth/register",{
                username, 
                email, 
                password,
            });
            res.data && window.location.replace("/login");
            console.log(res);
        }catch(err){
            setError(true);
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
```

my form code

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<div className="mb-3">
<label className="form-label">User Name</label>
<input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={e=>setUsername(e.target.value)} value={username} />
</div>
<div className="mb-3">
<label className="form-label">Email address</label>
<input type="email" className="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" onChange={e=>setEmail(e.target.value)} value={email} />
<div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
</div>
<div className="mb-3">
<label className="form-label">Password</label>
<input type="password" className="form-control" onChange={e=>setPassword(e.target.value)} value={password} />
</div>
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Is it just a case of you getting the POST URL wrong? You have it as `/auth/register` but the proxy is set up on `/api`. So I would have thought the URL should be `/api/auth/register` instead.

Comment: @GregL - when I am using with /api/auth/register - I am getting error - POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register 404 (Not Found) .

Comment: This could be something wrong with your backend? Have you checked to see if there's any log on the backend? Maybe post the SignUp.js code too